# Trouble opening a specific workbook, and running a find formula to a userform

Tags: excel, vba, copying

I have the code below, which works perfectly when run from a command button on sheet 6 of "filename.xlsx".  (name changed, as it's a work file)   It opens a userform, where I enter the date in a textbox (dateFind),  it then populates 100 labels on the userform, then from sheet 29, it gets the appropriate week number.

Once it has all the info on the userform, it then moves it into tester.xlsx. and then saves the file using variables from the userform to create the filename. A quick check of the figures from the open userform to tester is done, then click OK on the message box to close form.

(Sorry if that's long winded, I thought the above might help to explain what I'm doing)  :)

What I need it to do though is run from a button on another user form.  This requires referencing the full filepath of the filename.xlsx as when it's run at work eventually, both "filename.xlsx" and "tester.xlsx" will be in different folders.

I've tried set = workbooks.open and then the full file path for both sheet 29 and sheet 6, and get a run time error 424.  Object required.  in sheet 29.  I assume that that'll be the case for sheet 6 as well, but it's there.

```
Private Sub cb1_Click()
Dim wkbk As Workbook
Dim SubDate As Range
Dim WkNo As Range
Dim txt As String
Dim Filename As Variant

    With Application
         .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
         .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
```

'Suggested Edited code start

```
    Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open ("F:\Users\e-lia\Desktop\filename.xlsx" )

    Set WkNo = sourceWb.Sheets("Sheet29").Range("A:A").Find(what:=dateFind.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not WkNo Is Nothing Then
    Me.WeekNo.Caption = WkNo.Offset(0, 1).Text
    Else
    MsgBox "Please check the date, and try again!"
    End If
    Set SubDate = sourceWb.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A:A").Find(what:=dateFind.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not SubDate Is Nothing Then
```

'Suggested Edited code end

```
    Me.MON.Caption = SubDate.Offset(0, 0).Text  ‘another 100 similar lines

    Else
    MsgBox "Please check the date, and try again!"
    End If
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open("F:\Users\e-lia\Desktop\tester.xlsx")


    wkbk.Sheets(3).Range("M21") = MON.Caption   ‘another 100 similar lines


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Users\e-lia\Desktop\filename for - Wk No." & WeekNo.Caption & " - for the Week ending " & FRI.Caption & ".xlsx"
    MsgBox "The filename for Wk No. " & WeekNo.Caption & " and week ending " & FRI.Caption & " has been created and saved to the Desktop Folder."
    wkbk.Close False
    With Application
      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Which line of the code triggers the error?  I suspect you may want `set sourceWb=workbooks.open(filename): sourceWb.Sheets("Sheet29").Range...`.  That is, just as you reference tester.xlsx through a Workbook variable, reference filename.xlsx the same way.  Remember, you can edit your question to include more information.

Comment: Hi cxw, thanks for the help.  The line Set WkNo = .. triggers the error.  I'm trying to add the new code you suggested, but I'm getting a runtime error 9 on Set WkNo = sourceWb.Sheets("Sheet29").Range("A:A").Find(what:=dateFind.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole). Have I understood you correctly?  I'm new to this..  (Code above edited to show the changes)

Comment: Is there a "Sheet29" in that file?  Runtime error 9 is `Subscript out of range`, which means it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Darrell.  There is.  I just ran it via the button on the original sheet, and it still works.  Apart from this file being renamed from xlsm to xlsx, it's still the same workbook

Comment: Also, I commented out the references to Sheet 29, so it only started from sheet 6, and got the same error..  :(

Comment: Hi.  I don't know why, but on changing the "Sheet6" and "Sheet29" references to the actual name of each sheet, it worked.  :)  Thank you both for your help.  Only just got here, so I don't know if you mark these as solved?

Comment: I will post as an answer so that you can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have been using the Codename instead of the actual Sheetname.  The Sheetname is the name on the tab and the Codename is the name you will see in the project window not in parentheses.  They can both be used, but there are different ways to use them.  Looking at the example, you would refer to `ThisWorkbook.Sheet1` using the codename and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")` using the sheet name.
[image: Project Window]